# Matrix computation without computing the inverse

Tags: matrices

Hi I'm trying to figure out a way to solve the question $$           
\underline{x} = 
\mathbf{B}^{-1}(\mathbf{C}^{-1}+\mathbf{A})(2\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{I})\underline{w}
$$
without actually computing any of the inverses.
($\mathbf{A},$ $\mathbf{B}$ ,$\mathbf{C}$
are $n\times n$ matrices, $\mathbf{B}$ ,$\mathbf{C}$
nonsingular, and $\underline{w}$ is an $n-$vector)

How can this be done?

Is this more efficient than computing the inverses and do the calculation?
How does the operation count compare?

Comment: If you have no other information on the matrices, what else could you do?

Comment: The only solution I can think of is to multiply both sides by B and C to get rid of the inverses but I still can't make inverse of C disappear.

Comment: B. t. w., what is the unknown, $x$ or $w$?

Comment: x is the unknown here

Comment: Then if you multiply both sides, you won't have $x$…

Comment: i know, but I guess I could then do Gaussian Elimination to solve the equations.

Comment: I don't  see whare you want to go: you have your solution: x= …. You'd like to simplify the formula, but since there is no relation between $A,B$ and $C$, I really don't see how you possibly could simplify. unless $w$ has some property you didn't mention.